# Center in ConTeXt

Tags: horizontal-alignment, context

What is the equivalent of `\begin{center}...\end{center}` in ConTeXt? I know `\raggedcenter`, but that not an environment. I could define one command, but surely there is anything like that predefined.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For one line use `\midaligned{Some text}`, or in newer versions:

```
\startlinealignment [middle]
  Some text
\stoplinealignment
```

for multiple lines use

```
\startalignment [middle]
  \input knuth
\stopalignment
```

See [Wiki - alignment](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startalignment)